# Wait for magic packet option not listed under network adapter

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

I'm setting up Wake on Lan for my PC, but there doesn't seem to be the option to allow "wait for magic packet" under my network adapter. Do I just not have this option?

[image]
<sup>**Network adapter**  (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: have you tried updating the driver?

Comment: Its possible that adapter does not have the wake on magic packet functionality.

Comment: Updating my drivers lists the option. I figured it wasn't needed since this computer is new, but looks like I was wrong. Thanks @Moab

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating my drivers lists the option. I figured it wasn't needed since this computer is new, but looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, after installing a full driver package for my INTEL ethernet card, I'm able to see the 'Wake on magic packet'

Link for driver package: https://www.intel.com.br/content/www/br/pt/download/15084/intel-ethernet-adapter-complete-driver-pack.html

Comment: This solved it for me, too. Link to English download page: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/15084/intel-ethernet-adapter-complete-driver-pack.html